# Initialization of the constant parameters of a constructor

Tags: c++

```
class TrainRoute
{
private:
    string departure;
    string destination;
    char* trainCode;

public:
    TrainRoute()
    {
        departure = "";
        destination = "";
        trainCode = nullptr;
    }
TrainRoute(string departure, string destination, const char* trainCode : departure(departure),destination(destination)
    {
        this->departure = departure;
        this->destination = destination;
        
    }
```

The problem is when initializing the const char * trainCode parameter in the constructor other than nulptr

In what ways can I use this parameter?

Comment: Why `char*` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: If you must change `char* trainCode;` to `const char* trainCode;` but it would be better to change it to `string trainCode;`.

Comment: This code has a syntax error in the 2nd constructor and won't compile (missing a `)` before `:`). Also, why the double initializations in the 2nd constructor? If you use the constructor's member initialization list, you don't need the redundant assignments in the constructor's body

Comment: What "problem"? What happens when you compile/run this code? Why is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here:

1. As Remy pointed out you are missing a bracket
2. You have your parameter names the same as your member names - this causes ambiguity (at least to the code writer) and this is why you have to use `this->`. One fairly standard way to get around this is to have your members start with `m_`, but there are other schemes.
3. By using char* you will need to create dynamic memory and manage this, which is a pain, as others pointed out, use std::string.

But if you must  use char arrays then: [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hM3nGo)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class TrainRoute
{
private:
    string m_departure;
    string m_destination;
    char* m_trainCode;

public:
    TrainRoute()
    {
        m_departure = "";
        m_destination = "";
        m_trainCode = nullptr;
    }

    TrainRoute(string departure, string destination, const char* trainCode)
        : m_departure(departure)
        , m_destination(destination)
    {
        m_trainCode = new char[strlen(trainCode)];
        strcpy(m_trainCode, trainCode);
    }

    ~TrainRoute()
    {
        // Most now free this mem
        delete[] m_trainCode;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "dept: " << m_departure << std::endl;
        std::cout << "dest: " << m_destination << std::endl;
        std::cout << "code: " << m_trainCode << std::endl;
    }
};    

int main()
{
    TrainRoute tr("start", "dest", "code123");
    tr.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Note: here I have to create a new memory buffer to store the string into and copy the parameter string into it AND in the destructor make sure I free that memory... So by using std::string - you don't need any of that :)

Here is the same code, but using a string member to store the `const char *` (assuming you must take a string as a parameter): [using string](https://godbolt.org/z/hsaGzP) - it also has a few other modern c++ improvements

Comment: I use your code but it prints a strange  message for m_trainCode: ═══²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌

Comment: @Mircea what exactly are you passing in to `TrainRoute(string departure, string destination, const char* trainCode)`? - if you pass a `const char *` then (as the live example shows) the code works as designed. It will not handle an array of "data" only a c-string (null terminated)

Comment: For example this is wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/3af7hx - if you don't pass in a null terminated string then you probably don't want a char * at all, you might want a `uint8_t *` and a length field as well...